# Python - multiple iterations over lists of different size

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

Does anyone could help with this code? I'm writing this code to compute some values over some equations. I satarted by reading the CSV values into a dictionary, but after calculating the values to reach the final set of parameters, I cannot find a way to iterate repeatedly over the same list.

To simply, I have two input lists dPdT and listT. I need to iterate every parameter of list dPdT over listT and produce three different lists P.

I thank anyone willing to help. This is a study project for a course.

```
# Request user's interval parameters for calculations
print("Inform the temperature range and interval (°C). Only integers.")
minT = int(input("Min: "))
maxT = int(input("Max: "))
stepT = int(input("Temperature interval: "))

# create a list of temperature values to compute pressure parameters
listT = []

for x in range(minT, (maxT+stepT), stepT):
    listT.append(x)

# Open CSV file in read mode to acces data and read it into a dictionary
with open(CSVfile, "r") as CSV:
    reader = csv.DictReader(CSV)

    listDict = []

    # Creates a list of dictionaries with the fluid inclusion parameters
    for lines in reader:
        listDict.append(lines)

    # Define list parameters to be computated
    a, b, c, dPdT, P = [], [], [], [], []

    # Loop iterates over the dictionary list and computates parameters a,b,c stored in lists a,b,c
    for i, rows in enumerate(listDict):
        a.append(i)
        b.append(i)
        c.append(i)
        if "sal" in rows:
            a[i] = (18.28 + 1.4413 * float(rows["sal"]) + 0.0047241 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 2
                + 0.0024213 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 3 + 0.000038064 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 4)
            b[i] = (0.019041 - 1.4268 * 0.01 * float(rows["sal"]) + 5.66012 * 0.0001 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 2
                - 4.2329 * 0.000001 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 3 - 3.0354 * 0.00000001 * float(rows["sal"]) ** 4)
            c[i] = (- 1.5988 * 0.0001 + 3.6892 * (10 ** -5) * float(rows["sal"]) - 1.9473 * (10 ** -6) * float(rows["sal"]) ** 2
                + 4.1674 * (10 ** -8) * float(rows["sal"]) ** 3 - 3.3008 * (10 ** -10) * float(rows["sal"]) ** 4)

    # Loop iterates over the dictionary list and computates dPdT to store the values in list dPdT
    for i, rows in enumerate(listDict):
        dPdT.append(i)
        if "th" in rows:
            dPdT[i] = a[i] + b[i] * float(rows["th"])  + c[i] * float(rows["th"]) ** 2

    # Loop populates list P (pressure values)
    for i in range(len(listT)):
        P.append(i)
    
    # problem starts here: I need to iterate over the listT or P, repeating it for every dPdT values.
    # Loop to calculate P based on lits dPdT and listT. 
    while i in range(len(dPdT)):
        for j in range(len(P)):
            P[j] = dPdT[j] * listT[j]
```

Comment: Can you link the error message please ?

Comment: No error message yet. I can't just think on a way to to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to iterate every parameter of list dPdT over listT and produce three different lists P.

I'm sorry it's hard to understand your question. Explain this line.

Do you want to multiply each element in dPdT with each element in listT resulting in a P array of length = len(dPdT) * len(listT) ??? Because your current code is doing exactly that.

Edit:

Ok, I understand. I think the best way to go about it is to make P a 2d array. Basically, P will be a  huge array containing multiple arrays within it. len(P) = len(dPdT) and len(P[i]) = len(listT)

```
P = [ [0 for i in range(len(listT)] for j in range(len(dPdT)) ]
for row in range(len(dPdT)):
     for col in range(len(listT)):
          P[row][col] = dPdT[row] * listT[col]
```

I hope this is what you wanted. Basically, the nth element of P will also be array containing the numbers in listT all multiplied by the nth element of dPdT.

:)

Comment: Yes. But, I believe it should result in more than one P arrays (one for each dPdT value). I know this is not the way it should be solved.

Comment: Each value in dPdT should behave like a constant in the equation P[i] = dPdT * lisT[i]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!